# How do I synchronize the div while scrolling?

Tags: jquery, html, css, parallax

I am trying to handle the div synchronization while scrolling. Basically, I have only two divs which I want to control as page scroll and fixed the second div once it reaches the top.
Please check the attached gif icon.

You can also [check](http://projects.devzeststudio.com/drones/v3/) my progress so far.

The issue in my code is: both divs reaches at the top as soon as I scroll a page.

The jquery which I used to do that is following:

```
jQuery(document).on('ready', function() {
    "use strict";
    /* -------------------------------------
            Set Page Height
    -------------------------------------- */
    function headerFullScreen() {
        var _vph = jQuery(window).height();
        jQuery('#header').css({'height': _vph + 'px'});
    }
    function imgBoxFullscreen() {
        var _vph = jQuery(window).height();
        jQuery('#imgbox').css({'height': _vph + 'px'});
        jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
            if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() >= _vph - 68){
                jQuery('.navigationarea').addClass('ontop');
            }
        })
    }
    window.onresize = function() {
        headerFullScreen();
        imgBoxFullscreen();
    }
    var refreshId = setInterval(refresh, 500);
    function refresh() {
        headerFullScreen();
        imgBoxFullscreen();
    }
    /* -------------------------------------
            FIXED LOGO AND NAV
    -------------------------------------- */
    jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
        var scrollTop = 1;
        if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() >= scrollTop){
            jQuery('.logoholder, .navigationarea').css({
                position : 'fixed',
                top : '0',
                margin : '0'
            });

            jQuery('.navigationarea').addClass('ontop-mobile');
            jQuery('.navigationarea').addClass('ontop');
            jQuery('.menu_lis').addClass('top_menu');
            jQuery('.straight-menu').addClass('hide_bottom_menu');


        }else{
                    jQuery('.navigationarea').removeClass('ontop-mobile');
                    jQuery('.navigationarea').removeClass('ontop');
                    jQuery('.menu_lis').removeClass('top_menu');
                    jQuery('.straight-menu').removeClass('hide_bottom_menu');

        }
        if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() < scrollTop){
            jQuery('.logoholder').removeAttr('style');
            jQuery('.navigationarea').removeClass('ontop-mobile');
            jQuery('.navigationarea').removeClass('ontop');
            jQuery('.navigationarea').removeAttr('style');
        }
    })
});
```

I have also attached the gif to show how it need to work.
Any help please?[image: This is how the div supposed to work]

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

A simplified version of the script

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (scrollTop > 0) {
    $(".logo,.menu").css({
      position: 'fixed',
      top: '0',
      margin: '0'
    });
  } else {
    $(".logo,.menu").removeAttr('style');
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j3no7uy5/

Comment: it works fine, but the only thing I want to move the divs as much as a user scrolls the page.
The only issue now is the both divs immediately goes to the top as soon as we scroll a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Dan just left a little detail out of his answer on accident. You need to compare the div's initial offset from the top of the page to the amount you have scrolled.

If the scroll distance is greater than the initial offset, then you make it sticky. Otherwise, you revert it to its original style.

You can do the styling with jQuery's `.css()` as I'm doing below, or you can toggle classes, or both. It's whatever works for you.

Example:

```js
$(function() {
  var targetDiv = $('#section1').find('.section-container');
  var sec1offset = targetDiv.offset().top;

  $(document).scroll(function() {

    var distY = $(document).scrollTop();

    if (sec1offset <= distY) {
      $(targetDiv).css({
        position: 'fixed',
        top: '0',
        left: '10vw',
        zIndex: '0'
      });
    } else {
      $(targetDiv).css({
        position: '',
        top: '',
        left: '',
        zIndex: ''
      });
    }
  });

});
```

```css
#section0 {
  background-color: midnightblue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60vh;
}

#section1 {
  background-color: gold;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60vh;
}

#section1 .section-container {
  width: 80%;
  height: 30vh;
  position: relative;
  top: 20vh;
  left: 10vw;
  background-color: firebrick;
}

#section2 {
  background-color: midnightblue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="section0"></section>
<section id="section1">
  <div class="section-container"></div>
</section>
<section id="section2"></section>
```